# Statistics problem about computing UMVUE(Uniformly Minimum Variance Unbiased Estimator)

Tags: statistics

Let $\underline{X}$ ~ Be(p) of size n. Obtain UMVUE for p.

My idea is the MLE of that problem is the UMVUE but i think its wrong. Can someone help me?

Comment: One way is to find a complete sufficient statistic for p, then a function of that whose expectation is p will be the UMVUE of p. don't have time to go through the steps

Comment: If MLE is unbiased and complete sufficient, it has to be UMVUE. Where are you stuck?

Comment: $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(X_i)}{n}$$

Comment: Is that a complete sufficient?

Comment: It is. You can prove this from definition using the distribution of $\sum X_i$.

Comment: So the expectation of that is the umvue for p. Thats the answer?

Comment: No, just it by itself is the answer. $T(x)=\frac{\sum X}{n}$ is the UMVUE. It is sufficient by the factorization theorem. It is complete because bernoulli is from exponential family, so sufficiency implies complenetess.  Lastly, $E(\bar X)=p$, so it is unbiased. So $\bar X$ is the UMVUE.

Comment: Can you show details i think we are on the same page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to show that $T=\overline{X}_n$ is the UMVUE for $p$

This is one; I chose this because it allow us to do further considerations about that important estimator:

$$\mathbb{E}[\overline{X}_n]=p$$

Thus $T$ is  unbiased and its variance is

$$\mathbb{V}[\overline{X}_n]=\frac{p(1-p)}{n}$$

Now let's calculate the lower bound for the variance of unbiased estimator for $p$ using Cramér-Rao inequality;

$$\mathbb{V}[T]\geq \frac{1}{-n\mathbb{E}\left\{\frac{\partial^2}{\partial p^2}\log f(x|p)  \right\}}=\dots=\frac{p(1-p)}{n}$$

Thus $T=\overline{X}_n$ is UMVUE for $p$ AND its variance also attains the Cramér Rao lower bound....and this does not happen so frequently among UMVU Estimators

---

here are the calculations for CR lower bound, as requested.

$$f=p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$$

$$\log f=x\log p+(1-x)\log(1-p)$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial p}\log f=\frac{x}{p}-\frac{1-x}{1-p}$$

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial p^2}\log f=-\frac{x}{p^2}+\frac{1-x}{(1-p)^2}$$

Now observe that $\mathbb{E}[X]=p$ and $\mathbb{E}[1-X]=1-p$ thus substitute and immediately conclude

Comment: Can you show full solution of cramer rao

Comment: @Sergio : added in the edited answer

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Can i ask one more problem to you?

Comment: Sir? Is it okay?

Comment: @Sergio this topic is closed. Post a new one

Comment: Can you help me solved this?

Comment: @Sergio $\theta \Sigma_i X_i$ is a pivotal qty. Use this to get a CI based on a $\chi^2$ distribution. For details post a new topic, I repeat.

Comment: This is the same question

Comment: Thanks for response sir

Comment: Why your answer is deleted?

Comment: why you delete sir?

Comment: @Sergio : for a downvote. I edited with an example and undeleted. If no upvote are registered I will delete it again definitively